# PHP Mongodb driver gives "unauthorized" error when running MongoDB->execute() with Mongo 2.4.0 using authentication

Tags: php-mongodb

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://sf:xxxxxx@localhost/sf');
$collections = $m->selectDB("sf")->getCollectionNames();
var_dump($collections); // prints collection names as expected

$collections = $m->selectDB("sf")->execute('function (){ return db.getCollectionNames(); }');
var_dump($collections); // gives error "unauthorized"
```

This has been reproduced on:

Mongo 2.4.0 , MongoDB PHP driver 1.3.6, PHP Version 5.3.8, Windows 7 32-bit

Mongo 2.4.0 , MongoDB PHP driver 1.3.5, PHP Version 5.3.2, Ubuntu 10.04.4

Any help?

Comment: Is the user you are using an admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's execute is just a wrapper to call eval which requires admin access to use.

From the documentation:

```
With authentication enabled, eval will fail during the operation
if you do not have the permission to perform a specified task.
Changed in version 2.4: You must have full admin access to run.
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! It is clear its usage should be avoided, but are you aware of any walk arounds?

Comment: For the code you are running there is a built in function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getcollectionnames.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection string for MongoDB. If it includes the database, try removing it. For example:

mongodb://sf:[pass]@localhost/sf

to

mongodb://sf:[pass]@localhost/

After this is done, select the database after the client is instantiated with authentication. I believe this should allow you to utilize the function. I believe it results in the authentication being done for the admin collection instead of the specified collection, perhaps providing access to this function.